# API Platform error with not nullable field

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have a simple entity

```
 /**
 * @var string|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $city;

 ...

  /**
 * @param string|null $city
 * @return CustomerAddressList
 */
public function setCity(?string $city): CustomerAddressList
{
    $this->city = $city;
    return $this;
}
```

If I try to pass `null` to the field `city` the result is a runtime exception instead of a validation error:

```
{
  "@context": "/api/v2/contexts/Error",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "The type of the address attribute must be string, NULL given."
}
```

If I change `nullable=false` to true then everything works fine, but it's not an acceptable solution.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Well the nullable attribute is exactly made to make the field accept null values. Why is it not an option to enable it?

Comment: Because I want the field nullable in the database and if the client makes a mistake and sends `null` as a value I would like to have a validation error.

Comment: You could add the @Assert\NotNull() annotation to cause a validation against NULL in the API, while leaving the database nullable.

Comment: As I said is not acceptable as a solution. The not null at the database level is a mandatory requirement

Comment: Oh so you don't want it nullable. Sadly API-Platform does a poor job here and requires that nullable value set in order to even execute the validation from asserting constraints.

Comment: Your best bet would be to write a custom transformer that does the validation on a DTO manually before the data is deserialized into the doctrine object.  (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#validating-data-transfer-objects)

Comment: Surely I can achieve the goal with Dtos, but I don't think they are the best solution. For every entity in the same situation, I should have a DTO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205659/discussion-between-pglongo-and-pat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
* @ApiResource(
*     denormalizationContext={"disable_type_enforcement"=false}
* )
```

Adding the `denormalizationContext` with `"disable_type_enforcement"=false` disable the validation of the request using Doctrine annotations.

```
{
    "@context": "/api/v2/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
    "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "city: This value should be not null",
    "violations": [
    {
    "propertyPath": ".city",
    "message": "This value should be not null."
},
```

If it's necessary to enforce the field to be of a specific type then it's necessary to add the proper `@Assert\Type(...)` as prior Symfony 4.3

Comment: I would set it to `true`, though. i.e. `"disable_type_enforcement"=true` . This is a workaround to a known issue: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/788